# Server-side validation for form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The default validation for the form I have works as expected. But when a user types in a valid email address and a password of three characters minimum, that doesn't mean the login credentials are valid.

So my question is:

> How can I set the model *email* and *password* to invalid after
>   **server-side validation**, so the input-fields get the class ng-invalid instead of ng-valid.

**My current code**

```
function IndexCtrl( $scope, $http )
{
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.submitLogin = function ()
  {
    $http.post( '/api/auth/login', $scope.form ).success( function( data )
    {
      if ( !data.success )
      {
        $scope.form.errors = [ data ];

        // here I also want to mark the models 'email' and 'password' as invalid, so they both get the class 'ng-invalid'
      }
      else
      {
        $location.path( '/' );
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you simply use $setValidity method?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I set status code to 400 when my AJAX calls return errors. This way you don't need to check or set `data.success` but instead just handle errors in the error callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tosh shimayama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238847/tosh-shimayama) gave the right answer. **$setValidity** is a method from the `NgModelController` and takes two parameters: `validationErrorKey` and `isValid`.

More information on **$setValidity**

> Change the validity state, and notifies the form when the control
>   changes validity. (i.e. it does not notify form if given validator is
>   already marked as invalid).

Source and further information [AngularJS: NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 3):

Client-side validation is quick, but it is easy to break, using for example - firebug.
You can stick with only server-side validation. Validate everything on server and return BODY with list of keys and error messages. Angular allows you to send data to server asynchronously, end user will see it as client-side validation, as there was no visible post-back.

See this example, try to click 'Save', and see error messages: [upida.cloudapp.net:8080/org.upida.example.angular/order/create?clientId=1](http://upida.cloudapp.net:8080/org.upida.example.angular/order/create?clientId=1)

You can download it:  [upida.codeplex.com](https://upida.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice validation directive that might be usefull https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/6v-AillQboI/D0OaZzV7Me0J

Answer (score 0):

I done something but its rails specific, maybe it could give someone an idea, or push in the right direction
https://github.com/fmatosic/bubblemevalid