# How to write a generic error handler for AngularJS Forms

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angularjs

This is a follow on question for this question:

[Server-side validation form Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155949/server-side-validation-form-angular-js)

So using that answer you could write some HTML in a template that would display a specific error for each error you give $setValidity.  For example here is one:

```
<input ng-model="user.lastName" required="true" id="lastNameField" name="lastName" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<span class="inlineError" ng-show="myProfile.lastName.$error.required">Required</span>
```

However, if I wanted to add one for last names must be 4 or more characters long I'd have:

```
<input ng-model="user.lastName" required="true" id="lastNameField" name="lastName" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<span class="inlineError" ng-show="myProfile.lastName.$error.minRequired">Last name must be at least 4 characters long</span>
```

My question is how could I write a generic handler for all errors on a field.  Something like:

```
<input ng-model="user.lastName" required="true" id="lastNameField" name="lastName" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<span class="inlineError" ng-show="myProfile.lastName.$error.required">{{myProfile.lastName.$error.required}}</span>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that you just want to indicate the validity of the form element?
Then, you can do:

```
<span ng-show="myProfile.lastName.$invalid">Input field is invalid.</span>
```

If you need to be more specific, you can use `ng-repeat` to iterate through
`myProfile.lastName.$error` object and display all the errors.
In this case, you'll have to have some error-name to error-message translation for
readability.

Comment: That's kinda helpful because I wasn't aware of $invalid, but I really mean the later part where I iterate over all error messages and display them.